# Launch an app with push notification after it has been terminated

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if there was a way to wake up an app that has been terminated by the user on ios8-9. By terminated I mean double click on the home button and swipe up.

Is it somehow possible to launch an app by sending a silent push notification so that `didreceiveremotenotification` gets fired and gives me some runtime ?

I have noticed that a fair share of my users terminate my app. As I rely heavily on background fetch, this a problem. My idea was to send silent push notifications to launch the app in the background and trigger background fetch.

Comment: Maybe, but Apple wouldn't allow it.

Comment: Have you found answer to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No That is not possible.

**Detail:**

When there is any new content on server you will send Remote Notification to your application to inform about that. (A Remote Notification is really just a normal Push Notification with the `content-available` flag set)

When application received this Remote Notification it calls following method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

In Documentation of this method it is clearly written:

> However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user
>   has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app
>   or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app
>   automatically again.

Reference:

- [objc.io: Remote Notifications](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/multitasking/#remote-notifications)
- [Apple Doc about application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

Comment: Maybe I can ignore when the user "force-quit" the app.
What happens when the device boots or when the user swipe-out the app (that isn't a force-quit, but a clean close)? And a notification with content-avaiable arrives? Will my app be open and called automatically?