# iOS: open the app (foreground, background, closed) when a notification is received

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm a manufacturer of intrusion alarm systems. Now I'd like to send an alarm (a very critical event) to the mobile phone of the user. However it's not acceptable to have a "standard" notification in the tray bar, because the user could ignore it at first. Or another notification could stop my notification.

I'd like to mimic the behaviour of the phone when an incoming call arrives: custom ringtone starts playing for many seconds, the display backlight activates, the vibration starts and so on. Only when the user taps something the ringtone should stop (or after many seconds or minutes).

I think the best method to send messages to a mobile device is through push notifications. However I don't know if the push notification could wake my app, even if it is in background or stopped.

It seems only apps targeting VoIP application can behave in this way. However my app isn't a real VoIP app, so there's a possibility Apple will not accept it.

Comment: I would setup a system that calls the users phone with a robot telling them to check their app. Or a SMS message. I don't think there are any other options than the one you described. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260779/launch-an-app-with-push-notification-after-it-has-been-terminated

Comment: SMS is not "insistent" for the user. He could consider it of low priority. The phone call is already implemented, but it is old-style (the user should answer and hear an automatic voice telling what happened).

Comment: You can send a silent notification to your app in all states except terminated. Now, if the user chooses to terminate the app that is going to tell them about their alarm going off, then that is their decision. Once your app gets the silent notification it can schedule a local notification with  a sound that repeats every minute until the user taps on it.

Comment: What happens when the user reboots the iPhone? What is the state of my app, if the user forgets to open it? Is it terminated or in background? I think it is terminated (not running). I can't be sure the user reopens my app after every reboot.
Is there a way to open the app automatically during startup? It seems it is impossible in iOS (maybe only voip apps could).